# $scope.ons.navigator.pushPage not work in init method

Tags: angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I am following init function in app.js

```
$scope.init = function () 
        {
            if(localStorage.getItem("id")!=null && localStorage.getItem("pass")!=null)
            {
                alert(localStorage.getItem("id")+" "+localStorage.getItem("pass")); 
                var id=localStorage.getItem("id");
                var pass=localStorage.getItem("pass");              
                $http({method: 'GET', url: site+'/login-web.php?txt_email='+id+'&txt_password='+pass}).
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) 
                {
                    if(data=='error')
                        navigator.notification.alert("Wrong username or password.",null,"Attention.!","Try Again.!");
                    else
                    {
                        localStorage.setItem("id", id);
                        localStorage.setItem("pass", password);
                        alert("fire");
                        $scope.ons.navigator.pushPage('dashboard.html',{title : 'title'});
                    }

                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) 
                {
                    alert("Please check Mobile Data.");
                    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                    // or server returns response with an error status.
                });         
            }
        },
```

and i am fire init from

```
<body ng-controller="AppController" ng-init="init()">
```

I want to like this if i am login first time then i need to login and i store id and pass in localstorage and every time when application is load and init method is fire and i check id and pass from localstorage and fire server method to check id and pass if its right login is done automatically.

I am using phonegap + onsenui + angular js.

Problem is from init method

```
$scope.ons.navigator.pushPage('dashboard.html',{title : 'title'});
```

is not redirect to dashborad.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with `$scope.ons.navigator.pushPage('dashboard.html',{title : 'title'});`. But I think inside your `<body>` tag, there is no `<ons-navigator>` tag which is needed in order to use that function. Moreover, you need to call the function inside a setTimeout otherwise it will be called before the DOM element finishes rendering. Do as follows:

Here is what you need to add to ur controller:

```
app.factory('DataService', function($http) {
    var service = {
        requestData: function(url) {
            return $http.get(url).then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                service.myData = data;
                return service.myData;
            });
        },
        myData: null,
    return service;
});

app.controller('AppController', function($scope, DataService)){
    $scope.init = function(){ setTimeout($scope.init_wait, 10); };

    $scope.init_wait = function () {
        if(localStorage.getItem("id")!=null && localStorage.getItem("pass")!=null){
            alert(localStorage.getItem("id")+" "+localStorage.getItem("pass")); 
            var id=localStorage.getItem("id");
            var pass=localStorage.getItem("pass"); 
            var url = ite+'/login-web.php?txt_email='+id+'&txt_password='+pass;

            DataService.requestData(url).then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                if(data=='error')
                    navigator.notification.alert("Wrong username or password.",null,"Attention.!","Try Again.!");
                else {
                    localStorage.setItem("id", id);
                    localStorage.setItem("pass", password);
                    alert("fire");
                    $scope.ons.navigator.pushPage('dashboard.html',{title : 'title'});
                }
            });      
        }
    }
};
```

Here inside your HTML

```
<body ng-controller="AppController" ng-init="init()">
  <ons-navigator>
    <!--Your HTML-->
  </ons-navigator>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But init() is called and value get from localstorage successfully but page is not redirect to dashboard.html

Comment: @PareshGami I think that's because of the promise inside your http service. I recommend getting your http data through a service as I updated in my answer. Then injecting it into your controller. It should work this time. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. You are changing app.factory right? but can you explain me how its work and call from init.